# AWS CDK DocDB::DBCluster fails with 'not a valid password'

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-documentdb

I am trying to use AWS CKD (JAVA) to create a DocumentDB instance.
This works with a "simple" plaintext password, but fails when I try to use a `DatabaseSecret` and a password stored in `Secrets Manager`.

The error I get is this:

```
1:44:42 PM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::DocDB::DBCluster                       | ApiDocDb15EB2C21
The parameter MasterUserPassword is not a valid password. Only printable ASCII characters besides '/', '@', '"', ' ' may
be used. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: c786d247-8ff2-4f30-9a8a-5
065fc89d3d1; Proxy: null)
```

which is clear enough, but it continues to happen, even if I set the password to something such as `simplepassword` - so I am now somewhat confused as to what am I supposed to fix now.

Here is the code, mostly adapted from the DocDB documentation:

```
    String id = String.format(DOCDB_PASSWORD_ID);

    return DatabaseSecret.Builder.create(scope, id)
        .secretName(store.getSsmSecretName())
        .encryptionKey(passwordKey)
        .username(store.getAdminUser())
        .build();
```

where the `ssmSecretName` is the name of the secret in SecretManager:

```
└─( aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id api-db-admin-pwd

ARN: arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:<ACCT>:secret:api-db-admin-pwd-HHxpFf

Name: api-db-admin-pwd
SecretString: '{"api-db-admin-pwd":"simplepassword"}'
```

This is the code used to build the DbCluster:

```
    DatabaseCluster dbCluster = DatabaseCluster.Builder.create(scope, id)
        .dbClusterName(properties.getDbName())
        .masterUser(Login.builder()
            .username(properties.getAdminUser())
            .kmsKey(passwordKey)
            .password(masterPassword.getSecretValue())
            .build())
        .vpc(vpc)
        .vpcSubnets(ISOLATED_SUBNETS)
        .securityGroup(dbSecurityGroup)
        .instanceType(InstanceType.of(InstanceClass.MEMORY5, InstanceSize.LARGE))
        .instances(properties.getReplicas())
        .storageEncrypted(true)
        .build();
```

The question I have is: should I use a `DatabaseSecret`? or just retrieve the password from SM and be done with it?

A sub-question then: what is one supposed to use the `DatabaseSecret` for then?
(NOTE -- this is the same class, almost, as in the `rds` package; but here I am using the `docdb` package)

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the `DatabaseSecret` creates a key/value pair as the secret:

```
{
  "username": <value of username()>,
  "password": <generated>
}
```

However, the call to `Login.password()` completely ingnores this, and treats the whole JSON body as the password (so the `"` double quotes trip it).

The trick is to use `DatabaseSecret.secretValueFromJson("password")` in the call to `Login.password()` and it works just fine.

This is (incidentally) inconsistent with the behavior of `rds.DatabaseCluster` and the `rds.Credentials` class behavior (who take a JSON SecretValue and parse it correctly for the `"password"` field).

Leaving it here in case others stumble on this, as there really is NO information out there.